# Bootstrap - Positioning within the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

this code shows my attempt at creating a navigation bar but I can find a way to position everything correctly. I have tried using col-md-3 for several elements but yet I am not able to position them. I was wondering if you would be able to put the search bar in the middle with the links aligned to the right.
[What I would like to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbnV.png)

The Faulty code is below.

Thank you!

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>NavBar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link navbar-brand ">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="mx-auto order-0">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon"
              aria-describedby="button-addon1">
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Link2</a>
      </li>
      </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing Bootstrap's [excellent documentation on their Navbar component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/) as it will better equip you to truly personalize your Bootstrap layout. It wouldn't hurt to also review their [utility documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) as several utility classes are well-suited for achieving your layout.

There are several ways you might go about achieving your desired layout, below is how I would approach it while still keeping the built-in Navbar functionality:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand pr-lg-5" href="#">Shopping District 1</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <form class="flex-fill my-2 my-lg-0 mx-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ml-lg-5">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link2</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In the above code sample I've included Bootstrap's class requirements to make your navigational menu collapse on smaller screens, along with the additional components to allow the toggle behavior.

I've also separated the `.navbar-brand`, `form` and `.navbar-nav` items as there is no reason to force them into the same list; Navbar uses Flexbox for its layout so each child element will already align itself accordingly.

For more fine-tuned structure I've declared a couple of margin and padding utility classes (`pr-lg-*, mx-lg-*` etc) to help create the spacing your illustration suggests you were looking for.  By using the `-lg-` variant these will only apply on larger devices.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to modify it to give somewhat of a result similar to what I was looking for!

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">

  <title>NavBar</title>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav pl-2">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link navbar-brand ">District 1</a>
      </li>
      <div class="mx-auto">
        <form class="mx-auto order-0 col px-md-5">
          <div class="mx-auto input-group mt-1">
            <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 380px;">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1"><img
                  src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/search--v2.png" alt="Search" class="mx-auto" width="20"
                  height="20"></button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
        </form>
        </div>

    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
      <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 120px;">
        <a id="one" href="" class="nav-link">Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item mr-5">
        <a id="two" href="" class="nav-link">Link2</a>
      </li>

      </li>
    </ul>


</body>

</html>
```